# Exponential Distribution $\lambda$

Tags: statistics

I assume $\lambda$ in exponential distributions is interpreted as **the chance of failure per unit of time**.

If so, how come this diagram have $\lambda$ greater than 1? That means there's no survival and the graph should be a flat line at zero?

[image]

**Textbook example:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, the rate refers to the expected number of failure per hour.

$\lambda$ can be any positive number.

Comment: So in the example, it's saying Chance of Failure in the Next Minute = Expected Number of Failure Per Minute? Shouldn't it be Chance of Failure in the Next Minute = $\frac{Expected Number of Failure Per Minute}{Expected Number of Failure + Success}$? Beucase $0\le$ chance $\le1$

Comment: Failure in the next minute means $Pr(X \le \frac{1}{60})=1-\exp(-\lambda \frac{1}{60}) \approx 1-(1-\frac{\lambda}{60})=\frac{\lambda}{60} $ by Taylor approximation.

Comment: Oh my god, I hate when they sneakily insert an "about" and then proceed to use a never-before-mentioned formula.